# redefinition of group name 'slug' as group 2; was group 1 at position 50

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am using Django Rest-framework and creating an endpoints for a application which has multiple Teams.
Each "Teams" have multiple "Channels". for simplicity I divide my application in two different apps.

1. TeamsAPI
2. ChannelsAPI

**I want to display the Channels as HyperLinkedField in Team List.**

```
channels:[
    127.0.0.1:8000/api/teams/<team_slug>/channels/<channel_slug>/)
]
```

### Team List Serializer

```
class TeamListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):


     channels = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True,
                                               read_only=True,
                                               view_name='channel-detail',
                                               lookup_field='slug')
     .
     .
     .(other feilds)

class Meta:
    model = Team
    fields = (
        'channels',
         .
         .
         .(other fields)
    )
```

### Teams URL

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('<slug:slug>/channels/', include('channelsapi.api.urls')),
  .
  .
  .(other urls)]
```

### Channel URL

```
 urlpatterns = [
  path('<slug:slug>/', ChannelDetailAPIView.as_view(), name='channel-detail'),
  .
  .
  .(other urls)]
```

### Channel Model

```
class Channel(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)

    team = models.ForeignKey(Team,
                         related_name='channels',
                         on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    pinned = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

### Channel Detail Serializer

```
class ChannelDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(read_only=True,
                                           view_name='channel-detail',
                                           lookup_field='slug')

    team = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(read_only=True,
                                           view_name='team-detail',
                                           lookup_field='slug')

    class Meta:
        model = Channel
        fields = (
            'url',
            'slug',
            'name',
            'description',
            'team',
            'pinned',
            'created_at',
            'updated_at'
        )
        read_only_fields = ('created_at', 'updated_at')
        lookup_field = 'slug'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by overriding the "HyperLinkedRelatedField".
Here is the code:

```
class ChannelHyperlink(serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField):
    view_name = 'channel-detail'
    queryset = Channel.objects.all()

    def get_url(self, obj, view_name, request, format):
        url_kwargs = {
            'slug': obj.team.slug,
            'pk': obj.pk
    }
        return reverse(view_name, kwargs=url_kwargs, request=request,     format=format)

    def get_object(self, view_name, view_args, view_kwargs):
        lookup_kwargs = {
            'team__slug': view_kwargs['slug'],
        'pk': view_kwargs['pk']
        }
        return self.get_queryset().get(**lookup_kwargs)
```

Now just simply call your custom serializer:

```
channels = ChannelHyperlink(many=True)
```